# update price of configurable product in product view page

Tags: product, price, custom-options, magento-1

Hi I am having multiple websites, for each website the price of a product is different. The price is based on the percentage given in admin panel system configuration. Each website has its own percentage value to hike the price of all the products

Suppose there is product A of 10 Rs

In website->store 1 the product price is 10 + (10*price_percentage/100)

So, to display it correctly on product details page I am editing 
`/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` like

```
$_price = $_productPrice * $percentageValue;
```

Its working fine for simple product. But I have some products with custom option where the custom option is a select box. The price is not updating with percentage value by above code.

Products with custom option shows the original price only. 10Rs as per above example

How can I update the price for these products?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to just run a script which updates all the prices. So you have an attribute with the base price and add your part on every price of every product. Then you don't have to hazzle the whole frontend and especially the checkout.